# iPhone Embedded Email

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to send an embedded email from my application.  I have it sending an email, but just want it to display a logo.  Any help or suggestions?  I do not want to send an image as an attachment.

Also, the image is not on a server, but rather in the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to send an HTML-formatted email containing the image inline.

In the doMFMailComposeViewController Class Reference there is documentation for the setMessageBody:isHTML: method. Is says this about inline images: "If you want to include images with your content, you must attach the images separately using the addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName: method."

Since you can set your own filename for the attachment, you can then include it in your HTML message using the normal `<img src="filename" />`. From my time sending emails with PHP, I can remember that the image is then not also shown as a separate attachment, but you should check this.